# spring: how to omit bean-name in a list?

Tags: spring

Do I have to give ids to the elements of a list of Bars ?

```
<list value-type="foo.Bar">
  <bean p:p1="someP1Value" p:p2="aP2Value" />
</list>
```

I get

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: 
Configuration problem: Unnamed bean definition specifies neither 'class' nor 'parent' 
nor 'factory-bean' - can't generate bean name
```

for this.

How can I omit the bean ids?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message is pretty clear. When defining a `<bean/`> you must either specify `class` or `parent` attribute:

```
<list>
  <bean class="foo.Bar" p:p1="someP1ValueA" p:p2="aP2ValueA"/>
  <bean class="foo.Bar" p:p1="someP1ValueB" p:p2="aP2ValueB"/>
  <bean class="foo.BarSubclass" p:p1="someP1ValueC" p:p2="aP2ValueC"/>
</list>
```

If you want to avoid exceesive use of `class` attribute, you can take advantage of `parent` feature:

```
<bean id="bar" abstract="true" class="foo.Bar"/>

<list value-type="foo.Bar">
  <bean parent="bar" p:p1="someP1ValueA" p:p2="aP2ValueA"/>
  <bean parent="bar" p:p1="someP1ValueB" p:p2="aP2ValueB"/>
  <bean parent="bar" p:p1="someP1ValueC" p:p2="aP2ValueC" class="foo.BarSubclass"/>
</list>
```

What are the `p:p1` and `p:p2` namespaces?

Comment: well, I thought "value-type" defines the class for the inner-beans, resulting in something of type List<Bar>. The ps are just some properties. Question is about omitting the name of the inner beans.

Comment: @Bastl: no, `value-type` is only to explicitly define the type when it is not clear. However you can use parent beans (see my second example).